# Select2 using ajax data, setting user selected value not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I have a select2 element using ajax to populate its data and now I have a table that when user select a specific row, it must reflect to the select2 element. Already tried this code, but not working. Already check the row values and it is correct and working fine so im sure select2 is the problem.

Here is my current code to populate data:

```
$('#UserLevel').select2(
        {
            theme: "bootstrap4",
            //theme: "classic",
            width: '100%',
            placeholder: "Select user level",
            //minimumInputLength: 3,
            ajax: {
                type: "post",
                url: 'OBUtilityWS.asmx/GetUserLevel',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                delay: 250,
                data: function (q) {
                    var params = {};
                    if (q.term) {
                        params['q'] = q.term;
                    }
                    else {
                        params['q'] = '';
                    }
                    return JSON.stringify({
                        parameters: params
                    });
                },
                processResults: function (data) {
                    return {
                        results: $.map(data.d, function (obj) {
                            return {
                                id: obj.UserLevel,
                                text: obj.UserLevel
                            };
                        })
                    };
                }
            },

        });
```

Here is my code for table row selection event:

```
$('#tbProfiles tbody').on('click', 'a', function () {
            var data = tbProfiles.row($(this).parents('tr')).data();

            $('#ProfileName').val(data['GroupProfileName']);

            $('#UserLevel').val(data['UserLevel']);
            $('#DesignationId').val(data['DesigID']);

            $('#UserLevel').trigger('change.select2');
            $('#DesignationId').trigger('change.select2');

            alert('Hello World!')
        });
```

What am i missing? Need your advice/help. Thank you!

Comment: can you show some html and if I understand right you mean when user chose some option from select2 then data of table should change automatic am i right?

Comment: @Nurbek Boymurodov, no sir. select2 data is already, and i have a table, like when i click table row value 1 then select2 must display selected value 1

Comment: after changing you should refresh select2

Comment: @Nurbek Boymurodov, idk if it needs to refresh since data is already loaded, i just want to display the selected value

Comment: you need it to refresh